# PHP - PDO select statement from _post variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to take values from a textarea and use them in a prepared select statement later in my code.  I am taking combining the values in the textarea into a single string ($output) that is referenced in the prepared statement.  If I just have a single value, and omit the concatenation of values it will work and return results.  However when I change it back to try and use the multiple values IN select statement no results are returned.  Im sure there is an issue with how I am doing the combining of values, but I am stuck at this point.  Below are the working example with 1 value, and the non working example with multiple values

This works for one value in the textarea

```
<?php
$user = 'public';
$pass = '';
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Inventory', $user, $pass );

$text = trim($_POST['ServerName']);
$query = $db->prepare("Select * from allhostids where hostname = :parameter");
$query->bindParam(':parameter', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row){
echo "<li>{$row['hostname']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['hostid']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['console']}</li>";
}
?>
```

This example which is what I need, does not return any results.

```
<?php
$user = 'public';
$pass = '';
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Inventory', $user, $pass );

$text = trim($_POST['ServerName']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$values = array_values($textAr);
$string = implode("','", $values);
$string = "'".$string."'";
$output = "(".$string.")";
//$output becomes the combined values from textarea like so('server1 ','server2 ','server3')

$query = $db->prepare("Select * from allhostids where hostname in :parameter");
$query->bindParam(':parameter', $output, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row){
echo "<li>{$row['hostname']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['hostid']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['console']}</li>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind each value separately and not as whole. If that doesn't help please post the $values content.

```
<?php
$user = 'public';
$pass = '';
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Inventory', $user, $pass );

$text = trim($_POST['ServerName']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$values = array_values($textAr);
$in = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($values ), '?'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM allhostids WHERE hostname IN ($in)";
$query = $db->prepare($query);
foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    $query->bindValue($i + 1, trim($value), PDO::PARAM_STR); //trim here
}
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row){
echo "<li>{$row['hostname']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['hostid']}</li>";
echo "<li>{$row['console']}</li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I made the changes as suggested, and now get results, but its only the last value from the text area not all of them.  I added three test records to the database server1, server2, server3 in the hostname field.  when I run the query it only returns the values for server3.  Below is a var_dump for $values right after the array_values line...."

`    array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "server1 " [1]=> string(8) "server2 " [2]=> string(7) "server3" }`

Comment: As you can see the server1 and server2 both have a space at the end - so you have to trim them. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much that did it.  Have been trying to get this working for awhile now.